# Set a filter for mails only from real users in microsoft outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How I can set a filter where mails are from individuals and not a group or distribution list? I am looking for probably appropriate options in custom search folders.

Comment: I'm afraid that there may be no such way for this. As a workaround, If there are only those specific groups, you can set a Move rule with "from peopel or public group".

Comment: For your reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/578ec844-d190-4401-9c07-75f2b16845ac/outlook-rules-and-alerts-from-group?forum=outlook